# getJSON replace object with variable

Tags: javascript, json, getjson

I have json file called list.json:

```html
{
  "nvg":{
  "Title":"title",
  "Description":"description",
  "Image":"",
  "URL":{
    "DEV":"https://dev.com",
    "TEST":"https://test.com",
    "PROD":"https://prod.com"
    }
   }
```

I have an array

```
var apps = ["nvg"];
```

I want to access the json data and extract the object based on the variable's value. Does anyone know how to pass the [i] into the json call?

```js
  var getConfig = $.getJSON( data, function( json ) {
    var apps = ["nvg"];
    
    apps.forEach(function(i){
      alert(i);
      alert(json.i.URL.DEV);
    });
  
  });
```

Like the code above, but to actually the "i" to pass the value defined in the array?

Comment: `json[i].URL.DEV`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the data using your Javascript object like an object or array.  This means you can do the following:

```
alert(json[i].URL.DEV);
```